# Come interpretare la frase "è l'agricoltore il mestiere del futuro?"

Tags: word-meaning

Di recente ho letto un articolo intitolato "È l'agricoltore il mestiere del futuro?" Ho consultato tre dizionari e ormai sono ben sicuro che nell'italiano moderno la parola "agricoltore" si riferisce soltanto a una persona e la parola "mestiere" si riferisce soltanto a una cosa (cioè un'attività manuale, un lavoro, una professione, un'abilità).

Come può essere un agricoltore (una persona) il mestiere (una cosa) del futuro? Mi domando se in questa frase "agricoltore" stia facendo da una specie di aggettivo, come per dire "è l'agricoltore (= il mestiere agricolo) il mestiere del futuro?"

Comment: La frase equivale a dire: "_è (fare) l'agricoltore il mestiere del futuro?_" Non ricordo abbastanza delle figure retoriche per dire se possa ricadere in una di esse (metonimia forse? Non sono sicuro).

Comment: Non mi sembra che siano in gioco delle figure retoriche. Semplicemente, agricoltore, come dottore, archeologo, avvocato, insegnante, commesso, infermiere, barista, ecc. sono parole che indicano mestieri o professioni. Si può discutere sul fatto che di solito queste parole sono al maschile, ma per il resto la frase che proponi è corretta.

Comment: Concordo con @RiccardoDeContardi. Sembra anche a me una metonimia, ovviamente non pensando alle figure retoriche come ad artifici poetici, ma come a meccanismi con cui la lingua genera nuovi usi. “Agricoltore”, come scrive l'OP, alla lettera è la persona che svolge quella attività; il meccanismo per cui, come dice giustamente Benedetta, la parola indica anche la professione non è lontano da quello per cui si dice “ascolto Mozart” etc., classici esempi di metonimie.

Comment: Oppure la potremmo considerare come un'ellissi: “fare l'agricoltore” o “il mestiere dell'agricoltore” che diventa semplicemente “l'agricoltore”. Bice Mortara Garavelli, nel suo *Manuale di retorica* accenna proprio all'impossibilità di dare sempre un'etichetta precisa ai fenomeni linguistici e fa notare come classici esempi di metonimie, come “in San Pietro” (detto della basilica) o “il Chianti” (detto del vino), volendo, si possano anche considerare appunto ellissi (“nella basilica di...”, “il vino del...”).

Comment: Sono più favorevole all’ellissi, @DaG. Se chiediamo a qualcuno: «Che lavoro / mestiere fai?», ci risponderà «(Faccio) l’agricoltore» o «Sono agricoltore». Se ci pensiamo, non ci sono altri modi per dirlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per indicare un mestiere, un'arte o una professione, si usa il nome della persona che li esercita con la preposizione di, articolata o non articolata.
Si dice ad esempio il mestiere dell'agricoltore, del ciabattino, dell'imbianchino, oppure di imbianchino.
Così la forma più completa per il titolo dovrebbe essere *"È quello dell'agricoltore il mestiere del futuro";* tuttavia l'italiano consente in molti casi di omettere parti del discorso per permettere di essere più incisivi e brevi. Questa forma retorica si chiama ellissi, e si può usare in diverse circostanze; nel caso che tu hai riportato l'omissione della preposizione non impedisce di capire il senso della frase, e rende molto più diretta la comunicazione, per cui non mi pare che si tratti di un errore grammaticale.

Di fatto non esistono molti nomi specifici per indicare il mestiere in se. Esistono nomi per indicare l'attività, come *"agricoltura"* oppure la persona, come *"agricoltore"*.

E molto comune usare il nome della persona, senza preposizione, al posto dell'espressione completa che indica il mestiere. Ad esempio compilando un modulo all'anagrafe, alla voce "professione" è difficile pensare che qualcuno scriva "quella dell'impiegato"; immagino che chiunque scriverebbe semplicemente "impiegato".